# Difference between PHP and Dot Net from QA Point of view

Tags: manual-testing, qa-role

How to identify whether the site is developed in PHP or Dot Net from QA Point of view?

The main purpose of asking the question was to know if there is any difference which a QA can make out just by looking at the site. It does not matter whether the site is developed in PHP or Dot Net, but the thought behind asking the question was to know the ways with which a QA person can identify it without checking the code.

If there are some ways with which we can identify it, what are they?

Comment: Why would you want this information as a QA? Any specific reason?

Comment: Ask the supplier/ development team?

Comment: There is no specific reason regarding this. As a QA, I wanted to know is there any way by which we can recognize, any structure or any layout.

Comment: Why would you care what the site is developed in - are there potential problems you want to avoid, possible issues you've heard about?

Comment: I have added some more details on raising this question.

Comment: I have a tough time justifying a reopen vote here. It might be an interesting topic, but I can't see the relevance to SQA here. If you're responsible for testing something *and* knowing what language it's developed in, I can't imagine the answer is harder than "ask the developers" which makes for a pretty lame question.

Comment: Got the point of closing this question. Yes, it would be an easier option to "Ask the developers" regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET websites you can usually find two hidden controls on every page named `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`. Keep that in mind if you are executing performance tests, because these parameters can be very tricky and you will probably need to manually correlate them in order not to lose session control.

Also, dynamic controls created on ASP.NET pages usually have names like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myTextBox`, where "myTextBox" is the name given by the programmer, "ContentPlaceHolder1" relates to the area where it is included and "ct100" is the default prefix inserted by .NET engine.